# Data type conversion error in using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am learning Rcpp and write the following two functions. The second function simply computes sum(log_gamma(x)) - log_gamma(sum(x)) where x is a vector.

Three data type conversion errors are returned, all of which I am not able to resolve. Can someone help me correct the codes? Thanks.

```
file330c72cf6532.cpp:8:37: error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::sugar::Vectorized<Rf_lgammafn, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >' to 'SEXP' in initialization
             SEXP lgamma_x = lgamma(x);
                                     ^
file330c72cf6532.cpp:10:45: error: cannot convert 'SEXP' to 'double' in initialization
             double up = sum_cpp(lgamma_x_vec);
                                             ^
file330c72cf6532.cpp:11:44: error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::sugar::Vectorized<Rf_lgammafn, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >' to 'double' in initialization
             double down = lgamma(sum_cpp(x));
                                            ^ 

cppFunction(
  'double sum_cpp(NumericVector x){
    double tmp = 0;
    int n = x.size();
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
      tmp = tmp + x[j];
    }
    return tmp;
  }')

cppFunction('double LogB_cpp(NumericVector x){
            Function sum_cpp( "sum_cpp" ) ;
            SEXP lgamma_x = lgamma(x);
            NumericVector lgamma_x_vec(lgamma_x);
            double up = sum_cpp(lgamma_x_vec);
            double down = lgamma(sum_cpp(x));
            return up - down;}')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two glaring errors being made here. The first issue is the use of a C++ as a regular *R* function when it shouldn't be (e.g. `sum_cpp`). The second is the issue with `lgamma` being a sugar expression returning an `Rcpp::NumericVector` and not a *scalar* (e.g. `double`).

---

The first issue comes up because you are using `cppFunction()`, which has its usage as a primary means to prototype *C++* code. For more extended *C++* usage, it is preferred that `sourceCpp()` is used. The use of `sourceCpp()` brings light to Rcpp attributes, which provide a means to surface *C++* functions into *R*. Specifically, within the *C++* script, one should use `// [[Rcpp::exports]]` above the desired *C++* function. In addition, if you need to use a *C++* function within another, it must be defined prior to its usage. Thus, define `sum_cpp` before `LogB_cpp` in the *C++* file. For an example of this, please see the [Rcpp Quick Reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-quickref.pdf) guide.

---

Regarding the second issue, this is easily corrected by either saving it as a `NumericVector` or using `[0]` to obtain the first result as a double.

Furthermore, for some reason you initially were saving into a `SEXP` and then converting into a `NumericVector` that step isn't need and has been omitted from below.

For example, place the following into **gamma_source.cpp**:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double sum_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x){
    double tmp = 0;
    int n = x.size();
    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
        tmp = tmp + x[j];
    }
    return tmp;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double LogB_cpp(Rcpp::NumericVector x){
    Rcpp::NumericVector calc_lgamma = lgamma(x);
    double up = sum_cpp(calc_lgamma);

    Rcpp::NumericVector sum_lgamma = lgamma(sum_cpp(x));
    double down = sum_lgamma[0];

    // Alternatively, you could do:
    // double down = lgamma(sum_cpp(x))[0];

    return up - down;
}
```

Then type: `sourceCpp("gamma_source.cpp")`. This assumes the working directory is the same as where "gamma_source.cpp" is. Otherwise, append the path.)

---

Example:

```
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("gamma_source.cpp")
x = c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5)
LogB_cpp(x)
## [1] 9.481571
```